# Hiding horizontal scrolling bar doesn´t work using simplebar library

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using simplebar library (https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) inside of an angular 6 project, when I added the simple bar in my html tag, it showed up an horizontal and a vertical scroll bar, so I want to show the vertical scroll bar only.

I've tried to hide the horizontal scroll bar with this CSS property:

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

and with this properties too:

```
width:100%" and "position:abolute" or "position:relative"

<div data-simplebar style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <div *ngFor="let example of examples;">
        <div>{{example.title}}</div>
            <p>{{example.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I expect only to show the horizontal scroll bar, but it doesn't seem to work, I don't know if I'm missing something or some CSS property, or if Angular is causing this problem.

Comment: Hello Juan, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SimpleBar library creates wrapper around your contents, hence the CSS overflow applied on your `div` will not hide the scrollbars.

Hide the horizontal scroll bar created by the plugin

```
.simplebar-track.simplebar-horizontal {
   display: none;
}
```

and disable the scroll on scrollable div created by the library.

```
.simplebar-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution worked, for some reason the "overflow-x: hidden" in the html tag didn´t work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SimpleBar` from `simplebar-react`, you can set the overflow in the style, as in the example below.

```
<SimpleBar style={{overflowX: 'hidden' }} autoHide={true}>
   ...
</SimpleBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using both of these commands at once.

- overflow-y: scroll;
- overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: It doesn´t work, I´ve been testing that part, when the first div of the ng-for appears, the horizontal scroll isn´t showed, but when the second element appears, it replaces the first element, so the new div container is renderized and the horizontal scroll appears

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think there are still no good answer to it.
When I am in need of hiding the horizontal scrollbar that's what I do:

```
.simplebar-scrollbar::before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```